# Sign Message using passphrase only

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, web3.py, python, authentication

I'm creating an authentication system using python and web3.py.
I'm trying to authenticate a user using

```
from web3.auto import w3

msg = 'sdb41554xcb4xc548cxd84dxcb'
message = encode_defunct(text=msg)
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
x = w3.eth.account.recover_message(message, signature=signed_message.signature)

if x.lower() == addr.lower():
     return 'AUTHENTICATED'
```

where **addr** is the account address of the user store in DB.

For this, the user has to provide his **private_key** every time. But what I want is that the user only provides the **passphrase**(which was earlier used while creating the account). His **public_key** is already stored in Database with his profile.

My question is:

> Is there any way that whenever the user provides his **passphrase** and
>   **public_key**(coming from DB), **private_key** is automatically retrieved and thus can be
>   used to sign the message? Any library or something present for the same?

I don't want the user to remember his private_key for the whole time.(While passphrase can be remembered)

**Other way:** I can import the account in Metamask and whenever he logs in, Metamask prompts open to sign the message. But this will make Metamask compulsory for the users which I don't want.

Comment: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html#web3.geth.personal.sendTransaction may be you should use smth like this

Comment: Where is the private key? Stored at the server or at the user?

Comment: @Ismael stored with the user only

Comment: @IgorSobolev `sendTransaction()` requires transaction id, and to get transaction id, the user has to perform some transactions which indirectly requires private key.

Comment: Why do you have problems retrieving the private key if the client has a single one? Unless you have a centralized service to manage keys the easiest way is to use a mnemonic and let each user store them, but then you have to sign everything at client side.

Comment: @Ismael private keys are impossible to remember. Every time a user logs in, he need to enter his private key. If anyhow he doesn't have access to get his private key, he will be unable to login.

Comment: You can use a [paper wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet) but everybody agree that it is not a good idea. There are several projects that try to make more easy to onboard uses perhaps you can try their ideas, for example [Universal Login](https://universallogin.io/).